# How do I truncate a .NET string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, truncate

I would like to truncate a string such that its length is not longer than a given value.  I am writing to a database table and want to ensure that the values I write meet the constraint of the column's datatype.

For instance, it would be nice if I could write the following:

```
string NormalizeLength(string value, int maxLength)
{
    return value.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

Unfortunately, this raises an exception because `maxLength` generally exceeds the boundaries of the string `value`.  Of course, I could write a function like the following, but I was hoping that something like this already exists.

```
string NormalizeLength(string value, int maxLength)
{
    return value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

Where is the elusive API that performs this task?  Is there one?

Comment: For the record, strings are immutable you can't truncate them you can only return a truncated copy of them.  Nitpicky, I know.

Comment: @John Weldon: That's probably why the member function doesn't exist -- it doesn't follow the semantics of the datatype.  On a side note, `StringBuilder` lets you truncate by shorterning the length, but you still need to perform the length check to avoid widening the string.

Comment: Whichever solution you pick, be sure to add a check for a null string before calling Substring or accessing the Length property.

Comment: @SteveGuidi - If that were the case, then there wouldn't be functions like Trim or Replace, which face similar semantic problems

Comment: @JohnWeldon More nitpicky than Microsoft themselves consistently are, as it happens - they're happy to document, for instance, [`.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim#System_String_Trim) in a manner that makes it misleadingly sound like it mutates the string: *"Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object."*

Comment: Why not just use Truncate from Microsoft.Toolkit.Extensions? Or perhaps it did not exist back then.

Answer (score 824, accepted):

**There isn't a `Truncate()` method on string, unfortunately.** You have to write this kind of logic yourself. What you can do, however, is wrap this in an extension method so you don't have to duplicate it everywhere:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
        return value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength); 
    }
}
```

Now we can write:

```
var someString = "...";
someString = someString.Truncate(2);
```

###### 2021-09-17 Alternative with suffix and c#8 nullable reference types.

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string? Truncate(this string? value, int maxLength, string truncationSuffix = "…")
    {
        return value?.Length > maxLength
            ? value.Substring(0, maxLength) + truncationSuffix
            : value;
    }
}
```

To write:

```
"abc".Truncate(2);          // "ab…"
"abc".Truncate(3);          // "abc"
((string)null).Truncate(3); // null
```

Comment: Great Solution, but remembered this only works in NET 3.5 and Up. Don't try it in NET2.0.

Comment: As long as you're in VS 2008, and presumably VS 2010, you could still do this even if targeting .Net 2.0. http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Using-Extension-Methods-In-Fx-20-Projects.aspx

Comment: This will fail when `maxLength` is a negative value.

Comment: @Bernard, this is supposed to fail if maxLength is negative.  Any other behavior would be unexpected.

Comment: I don't think the IsNullOrEmpty check is necessary? (1) If value is null, there should be no way to call this extension method on it. (2) If value is the empty string, the return statement as written (on the next line) will return the empty string.

Comment: You can call extension methods on null values.

Comment: It could be useful to add an optional third parameter, `string ellipsis = ""`, which you would use like `"myLongUsername".Truncate(9, "...")` which would return `"myLong..."`. The length of the ellipses would have to be accounted for where you truncate the string, so the code would basically change from `value.Substring(0, maxLength)` to `value.Substring(0, maxLength - ellipsis.Length) + ellipses`.

Comment: Great suggestion with the ellipsis, @jbyrd - I've just stumbled across this answer and your comment inspired me, so I used that idea. I was just as well ready to manually `+ "..."` elsewhere in the code, until I saw this. Thanks!

Comment: why not just `.Take(maxLength`) ?

Comment: @mmcrae: string.Take returns a IEnumerable<char>. Here are some ways to convert it to a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654190/ienumerablechar-to-string

Comment: It works, and it's clean ! I would have many questions but i suppose this is not the place

Comment: Why not `value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength))`?

Comment: @NetMage Math.Min basically does the comparison, but in your case you're always calling Substring. slight performance difference.

Comment: @JHBonarius Based on drzaus answer, which I didn't notice before, it is often faster then ternary.

Comment: @NetMage. I think it shouldn't be and I don't think the test is so good. Is he running in Debug or Release mode? His `val` is a constant. He throws away the result after computation. Who know what the optimizer is doing? I did my own test and found what he calls "smart trunc" to be faster: 10M iterations: "truncate" needed 924ms, "smart-trunc" 749ms. But my test also probably also not perfect.

Comment: A performance improvement idea: use `string.Concat(value.AsSpan(0, maxLength), truncationSuffix)` in replace of `value.Substring(0, maxLength) + truncationSuffix` to save 1 string allocation

Comment: Using C#8, you can use Range struct, which is short in notation, and has good performance:
return value[..Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength)];

Comment: I would suggest trimming the substring result if you do not want the ellipsis to have a space in front of it.
`? value.Substring(0, maxLength).Trim() + truncationSuffix`

You can also first Trim the message before checking the length
`return value?.Trim().Length > maxLength`

Answer (score 175):

Or instead of the ternary operator, you could use Math.min

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Truncate( this string value, int maxLength )
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) { return value; }

        return value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength));
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever! And the following expression is optimized to return a reference to the original string: `value.Substring(0, value.Length)`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not optimized for cases where value.Length is less than MaxLength which may be a common case in some data. Also the Length property on string should be capitalized.

Comment: This will fail when `maxLength` is a negative value.

Comment: @Bernard, so will a lot of things in the framework...but if I check for it...I either have to default `maxLength` to `0` or `value.Length`; or I need to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`...which makes more sense in this case, and is already thrown by `Substring` anyhow.

Comment: A bit shorter: `return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength));`

Comment: Shorter with range operator: `str = str[..Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength)]`

Answer (score 55):

Because performance testing is fun: (using [linqpad extension methods](https://gist.github.com/zaus/8055941))

```
var val = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(i => i % 10));

foreach(var limit in new[] { 10, 25, 44, 64 })
    new Perf<string> {
        { "newstring" + limit, n => new string(val.Take(limit).ToArray()) },
        { "concat" + limit, n => string.Concat(val.Take(limit)) },
        { "truncate" + limit, n => val.Substring(0, Math.Min(val.Length, limit)) },
        { "smart-trunc" + limit, n => val.Length <= limit ? val : val.Substring(0, limit) },
        { "stringbuilder" + limit, n => new StringBuilder(val, 0, Math.Min(val.Length, limit), limit).ToString() },
    }.Vs();
```

The `truncate` method was "significantly" faster. #microoptimization

*Early*

> - truncate10 5788 ticks elapsed (0.5788 ms) [in 10K reps, 5.788E-05 ms per]
> - smart-trunc10 8206 ticks elapsed (0.8206 ms) [in 10K reps, 8.206E-05 ms per]
> - stringbuilder10 10557 ticks elapsed (1.0557 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00010557 ms per]
> - concat10 45495 ticks elapsed (4.5495 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00045495 ms per]
> - newstring10 72535 ticks elapsed (7.2535 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00072535 ms per]

*Late*

> - truncate44 8835 ticks elapsed (0.8835 ms) [in 10K reps, 8.835E-05 ms per]
> - stringbuilder44 13106 ticks elapsed (1.3106 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00013106 ms per]
> - smart-trunc44 14821 ticks elapsed (1.4821 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00014821 ms per]
> - newstring44 144324 ticks elapsed (14.4324 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00144324 ms per]
> - concat44 174610 ticks elapsed (17.461 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.0017461 ms per]

*Too Long*

> - smart-trunc64 6944 ticks elapsed (0.6944 ms) [in 10K reps, 6.944E-05 ms per]
> - truncate64 7686 ticks elapsed (0.7686 ms) [in 10K reps, 7.686E-05 ms per]
> - stringbuilder64 13314 ticks elapsed (1.3314 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00013314 ms per]
> - newstring64 177481 ticks elapsed (17.7481 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00177481 ms per]
> - concat64 241601 ticks elapsed (24.1601 ms) [in 10K reps, 0.00241601 ms per]

Comment: Thanks for all the useful benchmarks! ... and Linkpad rocks!

Comment: Hmm, I don't agree with this bench. 1) The input string `val` is a constant. 2) The truncation length `limit` is constant for all 10k iterations. 3) It seems the output is immediately discarded. All these factors can cause the compiler to optimize things away. I did my own bench and found what you call "smart-trunc" to on average be significantly (20%) faster than "truncate", and that was with 10M iterations in Release/production mode (I also found significant difference between running in Debug mode and Release mode)

Comment: @JHBonarius i figured that the YMMV caveat for performance tests should be somewhat obvious and i just wanted to get that ball rolling ;)  and even if you're absolutely right, don't forget we're talking about differences less than a thousandth of a millisecond...

Answer (score 50):

I figured I would throw in my implementation since I believe it covers all of the cases that have been touched on by the others and does so in a concise way that is still readable.

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length > maxLength)
    {
        return value.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }

    return value;
}
```

This solution mainly builds upon the [Ray's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776673/how-do-i-truncate-a-net-string/2776716#2776716) and opens up the method for use as an extension method by using the *this* keyword just as [LBushkin does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776673/how-do-i-truncate-a-net-string/2776689#2776689) in his solution.

Comment: This will fail when `maxLength` is a negative value.

Comment: @Bernard - I would recommend not passing a negative value for the maxLength argument as it is an unexpected value. The Substring method takes the same approach so there is no reason to improve on the exception it throws.

Comment: I don't think the IsNullOrEmpty check is necessary?  (1) If value is null, there should be no way to call this extension method on it.  (2) If value is the empty string, the value.Length > maxLength check will fail.

Comment: @JonSchneider, the IsNullOrEmpty is required because this is an extension method.  If you have a variable of type string that has been assigned a null, the compiler does not insert a null check before calling this method.  Technically, this is still a static method of the static class.

So: stringVar.Truncate(2)
Compiles as: StringExt.Truncate(stringVar, 2);

Comment: The lack of an `IsNullOrEmpty` and the subsequent `NullReferenceException` is a feature, not a bug. Just as `str.Substring(0,10)` throws if `str` is null, it makes sense for `str.Truncate(10)` to do likewise.

Answer (score 49):

In .NET 4.0 you can use the `Take` method:

```
string.Concat(myString.Take(maxLength));
```

Not tested for efficiency!

Answer (score 40):

Another solution:

```
return input.Substring(0, Math.Min(input.Length, maxLength));
```

Comment: Very elegant solution +1

Comment: Nice, but this won't work on a string that is null.

Comment: This looks too similar to this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2776720/475876

Answer (score 32):

You could use LINQ... it eliminates the need to check string length.  Admittedly maybe not the most efficient, but it's fun.

```
string result = string.Join("", value.Take(maxLength)); // .NET 4 Join
```

or

```
string result = new string(value.Take(maxLength).ToArray());
```

Comment: why is this not the accepted answer? What's most straight forward, writing your own Extension method that you need to maintain/document, or using something BUILT IN like .Take

Comment: @mmcrae Linq might be more straight forward, but it's also a lot slower. My benchmark says ~400ms for Linq and only ~24ms for Substring for 1 million iterations.

Comment: This solution shouldn't be ever used. As said in two above comments, there always is memory allocation, even when existing string is not bigger than the max length. Also it's very slow.

Answer (score 23):

I did mine in one line sort of like this

```
value = value.Length > 1000 ? value.Substring(0, 1000) : value;
```

Comment: Quick, simple and fast. This is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

In C# 8 the new Ranges feature can be used...

```
value = value[..Math.Min(30, value.Length)];
```

Comment: This is easily the best way now. One line, no extension method, bueno! Highly suggest this be switched to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

The .NET Framework has an API to truncate a string like this:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(string, int);
```

But in a C# app you'll probably prefer to roll your own than taking a dependency on Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, whose main raison d'etre is backwards compatibility.

Comment: "The .NET Framework has an API" you are contradicting yourself. That's a VB.NET API

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - it's an API that is shipped with the .NET Framework, and can be called from any managed language.

Comment: The VB DLL has a lot of good stuff in it. Why are so many c# devs against it?

Comment: No .NET Core support currently, unfortunately. Indeed, the entire `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings` modules in .NET Core is [pretty empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings?view=netcore-2.0).

Comment: While I agree with Joe comment, still I don't feel right calling something specific for VB from other languages. If there are so much good stuff in "VB DLL", why not put it in some shared place? Who knows what Microsoft will do with these stuff tomorrow? Stop support or something..

Answer (score 16):

Seems no one has posted this yet:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Truncate(this string s, int maxLength)
    {
        return s != null && s.Length > maxLength ? s.Substring(0, maxLength) : s;
    }
}
```

Using the && operator makes it marginally better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but here is a nice solution:

```
public static string Truncate(this string text, int maxLength, string suffix = "...")
{
    string str = text;
    if (maxLength > 0)
    {
        int length = maxLength - suffix.Length;
        if (length <= 0)
        {
            return str;
        }
        if ((text != null) && (text.Length > maxLength))
        {
            return (text.Substring(0, length).TrimEnd(new char[0]) + suffix);
        }
    }
    return str;
}

var myString = "hello world"
var myTruncatedString = myString.Truncate(4);
```

Returns: hello...

Comment: @SarjanWebDev That special character shows up as "." in cmd.exe

Answer (score 6):

Why not:

```
string NormalizeLength(string value, int maxLength)
{
    //check String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) and act on it. 
    return value.PadRight(maxLength).Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

i.e. in the event `value.Length < maxLength` pad spaces to the end or truncate the excess.

Comment: You generate twice as many string objects and it could throw a NullReferenceException from the PadRight call if value is null which is inappropriate, it should be an ArgumentNullException.

Comment: @Jeremy I don't understand " it could throw a NullReferenceException from the PadRight call if value is null"; have I not mentioned "//check string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) and act on it."

Comment: That function does not produce the string expected by the original question, but I'm not downvoting it because it can can handy for someone else.

Answer (score 6):

Still no Truncate method in 2016 for C# strings. 
But - Using C# 6.0 Syntax:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
  public static string Truncate(this string s, int max) 
  { 
    return s?.Length > max ? s.Substring(0, max) : s ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(s); 
  }
}
```

It works like a charm:

```
"Truncate me".Truncate(8);
Result: "Truncate"
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest method in recent C# would be:

```
string Trunc(string s, int len) => s?.Length > len ? s.Substring(0, len) : s;
```

It returns truncated value for longer strings and original string for other cases - including null input - which is treated by ? unary operator.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a **C# 9** one-liner:

```cs
public static string? Truncate(this string? value, int maxLength) => value is null or "" || value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value[..maxLength];
```

Comment: This is a nice one. The only observation I have is that it's better to use `string.Empty` than `""` for an empty string, for performance reasons...

Comment: @EdB this is a pattern match so has to be a string literal. That said, in normal expressions both `string.Empty` and `""` resolve to the same interned string at run time.

Comment: turns out that you are right (post .Net 2.0), I guess you pick up habits which have good reasons for them, and those reasons go away, but the habits remain!

Answer (score 5):

Taking @CaffGeek and simplifying it:

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength));
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

A similar variant with C# 6's Null propagation operator

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    return value?.Length <= maxLength ? value : value?.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

Please note, we are essentially checking if `value` is null twice here.

Answer (score 5):

My two cents with example length of 30 :

```
  var truncatedInput = string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? 
      string.Empty : 
      input.Substring(0, Math.Min(input.Length, 30));
```

Answer (score 4):

Kndly note that truncating a string not merely means justing cutting a string at a specified length alone but have to take care not to split the word.

eg string : this is a test string.

I want to cut it at 11 . If we use any of the method given above the result will be

**this is a te**

This is not the thing we want

The method i am using may also not so perfect but it can handle most of the situation

```
public string CutString(string source, int length)
{
        if (source== null || source.Length < length)
        {
            return source;
        }
        int nextSpace = source.LastIndexOf(" ", length);
        return string.Format("{0}...", input.Substring(0, (nextSpace > 0) ? nextSpace : length).Trim());
}
```

Comment: That is not what the original question asked but I'm not downvoting your answer because  it can come handy for someone else.

Answer (score 4):

I know there are a ton of answers here already, but this is the one I have gone with, which handles both null strings and the situation where the length passed in is negative:

```
public static string Truncate(this string s, int length)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || s.Length <= length ? s 
        : length <= 0 ? string.Empty 
        : s.Substring(0, length);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case there's not enough answers here, here's mine :)

```
public static string Truncate(this string str, 
                              int totalLength, 
                              string truncationIndicator = "")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || str.Length < totalLength) 
        return str;

    return str.Substring(0, totalLength - truncationIndicator.Length) 
           + truncationIndicator;
}
```

to use:

```
"I use it like this".Truncate(5,"~")
```

Answer (score 3):

The popular library **Humanizer** has a [Truncate](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#truncate-string) method. To install with NuGet:

```
Install-Package Humanizer
```

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers do not take into account for Span's which is more performant than the Substring of the string type in .NET

If you are not already aware there is a version of System.Memory (which provides Span, ReadOnlySpan, Memory, and ReadOnlyMemory's for cases like this:

As such simple implementation for this could be as follows:

```cs
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length > maxLength)
    {
        return value.AsSpan(0, maxLength).ToString(); /* Note the use of AsSpan instead of Substring. */
    }

    return value;
}
```

The method could theoretically be made to return `Span<char>` instead to avoid allocating a new string using the `ToString()` member of `Span<T>`.

The BCL itself internally uses Span's, ReadOnlySpan's, Memory's, and ReadOnlyMemory's where possible to avoid issues and to help optimize the code, especially when you compile arrays that are known at compile time and so using an property that returns that new'd up array as an `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` actually optimizes the code at runtime as then the JIT would not call `memcpy` on the data and instead uses it since it just returns a Span and as such is a window to the data that is already allocated ahead of time resulting in:

1. less allocations.
2. Less time spent allocating.
3. makes the code overall faster to use.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of (over)complexity I'll add my overloaded version which replaces the last 3 characters with an ellipsis in respect with the maxLength parameter.

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength, bool replaceTruncatedCharWithEllipsis = false)
{
    if (replaceTruncatedCharWithEllipsis && maxLength <= 3)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxLength",
            "maxLength should be greater than three when replacing with an ellipsis.");

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) 
        return String.Empty;

    if (replaceTruncatedCharWithEllipsis &&
        value.Length > maxLength)
    {
        return value.Substring(0, maxLength - 3) + "...";
    }

    return value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in .net for this that I am aware of - here is my version which adds "...":

```
public static string truncateString(string originalString, int length) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalString)) {
   return originalString;
  }
  if (originalString.Length > length) {
   return originalString.Substring(0, length) + "...";
  }
  else {
   return originalString;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your version will give strings that are 3 characters longer than the requested length, in case they are truncated. Besides, the triple dots are really just meaningful in representation, I would not store it in a database like that which is the use case that the OP gave.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer jpierson's answer, but none of the examples here that I can see are handling an invalid maxLength parameter, such as when maxLength < 0.

Choices would be either handle the error in a try/catch, clamp the maxLength parameter min to 0, or if maxLength is less than 0 return an empty string.

Not optimized code:

```
public string Truncate(this string value, int maximumLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == true) { return value; }
    if (maximumLen < 0) { return String.Empty; }
    if (value.Length > maximumLength) { return value.Substring(0, maximumLength); }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Note, that in my implementation I chose not to handle the case where maximumLength is less than 0 because I figured the only thing I would do is throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeExcpetion which essentially what string.Substring() does for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vb.net solution, mark that the if (although ugly) statement improves performance because we do not need the substring statement when string is already smaller than maxlength...
By making it an extention to string it is easy to use...

```
 <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function Truncate(String__1 As String, maxlength As Integer) As String
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(String__1) AndAlso String__1.Length > maxlength Then
            Return String__1.Substring(0, maxlength)
        Else
            Return String__1
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: In VB.net you can replace "Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(String__1)" with "String__1 <> Nothing". It's a little bit shorter. The default value for strings is an empty string. Using "<> Nothing" checks both null and the empty string cases. Test it out with: Truncate("", 50) and Truncate(Nothing, 50)

Comment: In VB you can do Left(string, maxlength)

Answer (score 1):

I know there are a ton of answers already but my need was to keep the beginning and end of the string intact but shorten it to under the max length.

```
    public static string TruncateMiddle(string source)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source) || source.Length < 260) 
            return source;

        return string.Format("{0}...{1}", 
            source.Substring(0, 235),
            source.Substring(source.Length - 20));
    }
```

This is for creating SharePoint URLs that have a max length of 260 characters.

I didn't make length a parameter since it is a constant 260.  I also didn't make the first substring length a parameter because I want it to break at a specific point.  Finally, the second substring is the length of the source - 20 since I know the folder structure.

This could easily be adapted to your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

With C# 8 range feature and considering all kinds of inputs:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, 0);
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : value[..Math.Min(maxLength, value.Length)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the possibilities discussed above I'd like to share my solution.
It's an extension method that allows null (returns string.Empty) also there is a second .Truncate() for using it with an ellipsis. Beware, it's not performance optimized.

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength) =>
    (value ?? string.Empty).Substring(0, (value?.Length ?? 0) <= (maxLength < 0 ? 0 : maxLength) ? (value?.Length ?? 0) : (maxLength < 0 ? 0 : maxLength));
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength, string ellipsis) =>
    string.Concat(value.Truncate(maxLength - (((value?.Length ?? 0) > maxLength ? ellipsis : null)?.Length ?? 0)), ((value?.Length ?? 0) > maxLength ? ellipsis : null)).Truncate(maxLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Truncate` extension method that compares the max length relative to the string length and calls `Substring` if needed.

If you want null handling behavior that parallels that of `Substring`, don't include a null check. That way, just as `str.Substring(0, 10)` throws a `NullReferenceException` if `str` is null, so will `str.Truncate(10)`.

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength) =>
        value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2776720/7032856), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15645194/7032856), here are two versions that will work for [negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776673/how-do-i-truncate-a-net-string?page=1&tab=votes#comment25176494_2776689) of 'up to' values as well. This first one doesn't allow negative values silently by capping at 0:

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ?
        value :
        value.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength)));
}
```

This one goes in circle:

```
private static int Mod(this int a, int n) => (((a %= n) < 0) ? n : 0) + a;

public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ?
        value :
        value.Substring(0, maxLength.Mod(value.Length));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string Truncate( this string value, int maxLength )
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) { return value; }

        return new string(value.Take(maxLength).ToArray());// use LINQ and be happy
    }
```

Comment: The `ToArray()` call here is just needless overhead; using e.g. `String.Concat` you can construct a string from an enumerable of characters without having to go via an array.

Answer (score -1):

*TruncateString*

```
public static string _TruncateString(string input, int charaterlimit)
{
    int characterLimit = charaterlimit;
    string output = input;

    // Check if the string is longer than the allowed amount
    // otherwise do nothing
    if (output.Length > characterLimit && characterLimit > 0)
    {
        // cut the string down to the maximum number of characters
        output = output.Substring(0, characterLimit);
        // Check if the character right after the truncate point was a space
        // if not, we are in the middle of a word and need to remove the rest of it
        if (input.Substring(output.Length, 1) != " ")
        {
            int LastSpace = output.LastIndexOf(" ");

            // if we found a space then, cut back to that space
            if (LastSpace != -1)
            {
                output = output.Substring(0, LastSpace);
            }
        }
        // Finally, add the "..."
        output += "...";
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Why do you precede your public method name with an underscore?

Comment: This code can also suffer from performance issues when used in code that is performance critical. Not only that but it also allocates more than it should with the checking. Now if it were modified to use spans then the performance of it would be improved.

Answer (score -3):

Truncate String

```
public static string TruncateText(string strText, int intLength)
{
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strText)))
    {                                
        // split the text.
        var words = strText.Split(' ');

        // calculate the number of words
        // based on the provided characters length 
        // use an average of 7.6 chars per word.
        int wordLength = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(intLength / 7.6));

        // if the text is shorter than the length,
        // display the text without changing it.
        if (words.Length <= wordLength)
            return strText.Trim();                

        // put together a shorter text
        // based on the number of words
        return string.Join(" ", words.Take(wordLength)) + " ...".Trim();
    }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }            
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. First, it should be a member function (although you have written it as an extension method). Second, the OP does not specify that the text has to be split and words have be truncated to approx. 7.6 chars per word.

Comment: 7.6 is just a number. you can write any other number you wish. This happened to be an average English word length. I found it on google. Using split is just an easy way to break down the words by space. I don't think that you want to display a half word! So unless you loop through to find empty space which will require more code, this is an easy way to truncate a string and display full words. This will ensure you that a string is not longer then the given length and you won't have broken words.

Answer (score -4):

This is the code I usually use:

```
string getSubString(string value, int index, int length)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Length <= length)
            {
                return value;
            }
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            for (int i = index; i < length; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(value[i].ToString());
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Please note that concatenating strings with += is an expensive operation, especially when rebuilding character by character.  .NET strings are immutable, which means in this case, a new string is created each time in your loop.

Comment: @SteveGuidi strings are not immutable, they just masquerade as immutable. I wish strings were true immutable primitives so I could have string and string?, but alas they are not primitives.

Comment: You say expensive as if the performance cost is significant, I changed it to use stringBuilder but I find that with += is easier to see what's going on, I just wanted the OP to easily understand the code.

Answer (score -4):

I'd Recommend using the substring method for the same effective functionality.

```
    // Gets first n characters.
    string subString = inputString.Substring(0, n);
```

This has the benefit of letting you splice your string from either side or even somewhere in the middle without writing additional methods. Hope that helps :)

For additional reference: https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Comment: If your string is smaller than n it will fail. The point of truncate is to prevent that.