# C#: Limit the length of a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, limit

I was just simply wondering how I could limit the length of a string in C#.

```
string foo = "1234567890";
```

Say we have that. How can I limit foo to say, 5 characters?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? Where do you want to do this? In the simplest case, just do `if (foo.Length > 5) { throw new Lemmons.StringTooLongException(); }`

Comment: Read this response:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776673/how-do-i-truncate-a-net-string

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Strings in C# are immutable and in some sense it means that they are fixed-size.
However you cannot **constrain** a string variable to only accept n-character strings. If you define a string variable, it can be assigned *any* string. If truncating strings (or throwing errors) is essential part of your business logic, consider doing so in your specific class' property setters (that's what Jon suggested, and it's the most natural way of creating constraints on values in .NET).

If you just want to make sure isn't too long (e.g. when passing it as a parameter to some legacy code), truncate it manually:

```
const int MaxLength = 5;


var name = "Christopher";
if (name.Length > MaxLength)
    name = name.Substring(0, MaxLength); // name = "Chris"
```

Comment: I would say that *all* strings are fixed length in .NET. But you can't declare that a *variable* can only accept strings of a certain length.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I'll edit my reply, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that create an error if there's a surrogate pair at the end of the string, with low surrogate being cut off?

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if C# was intelligent enough to pick the right letters to truncate "Jonathan" to "John". Most languages would probably just give you "Jona"...

Comment: @Carl: Ouch, you're right of course.

Comment: Alternatively:  text = text.Substring(0, Math.Min(MaxLength, text.Length));

Answer (score 41):

You could extend the "string" class to let you return a limited string.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         // since specified strings are treated on the fly as string objects...
         string limit5 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.".LimitLength(5);
         string limit10 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.".LimitLength(10);
         // this line should return us the entire contents of the test string
         string limit100 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.".LimitLength(100);

         Console.WriteLine("limit5   - {0}", limit5);
         Console.WriteLine("limit10  - {0}", limit10);
         Console.WriteLine("limit100 - {0}", limit100);

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }

   public static class StringExtensions
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// Method that limits the length of text to a defined length.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="source">The source text.</param>
      /// <param name="maxLength">The maximum limit of the string to return.</param>
      public static string LimitLength(this string source, int maxLength)
      {
         if (source.Length <= maxLength)
         {
            return source;
         }

         return source.Substring(0, maxLength);
      }
   }
}
```

Result:

> limit5   - The q
>  limit10  - The
>   quick
>  limit100 - The quick brown
>   fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you bother with the check. Couldn't you just do return source.Substring(0, maxLength);? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DonnyV. - `Substring` will throw an exception if either parameter is outside the bounds of the string.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that....gotcha

Comment: This will fail when maxLength is a negative value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) or source is null

Comment: string can be null...

Answer (score 17):

You can't. Bear in mind that `foo` is a *variable* of type `string`.

You could create your own type, say `BoundedString`, and have:

```
BoundedString foo = new BoundedString(5);
foo.Text = "hello"; // Fine
foo.Text = "naughty"; // Throw an exception or perhaps truncate the string
```

... but you can't stop a string variable from being set to any string reference (or null).

Of course, if you've got a string *property*, you could do that:

```
private string foo;
public string Foo
{
    get { return foo; }
    set
    {
        if (value.Length > 5)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("value");
        }
        foo = value;
    }
}
```

Does that help you in whatever your bigger context is?

Comment: Can I make a character array that is limited. Like in C/C++? For example: char blah[100];

Comment: Sure `char[] blah = new char[100];`.  Should you? No. Use strings and enforce size constraints with a wrapper class or a strictly defined interface (preferably the latter).

Comment: That `BoundedString` seems like a nice candidate for an implicit conversion operator from `string` to `BoundedString`.

Answer (score 11):

`string shortFoo = foo.Length > 5 ? foo.Substring(0, 5) : foo;`

Note that you can't just use foo.Substring(0, 5) by itself because it will throw an error when foo is less than 5 characters.

Similarly:

`string shortFoo = foo.Length > 5 ? foo.Remove(5) : foo;`

Comment: or foo.remove(5)

Comment: @Ferd love it. Thx. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

If this is in a class property you could do it in the setter:

```
public class FooClass
{
   private string foo;
   public string Foo
   {
     get { return foo; }
     set
     {
       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length>5)
       {
            foo=value.Substring(0,5);
       }
       else
            foo=value;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another alternative answer to this issue. This extension method works quite well. This solves the issues of the string being shorter than the maximum length and also the maximum length being negative.

```
public static string Left( this string str, int length ) {
  if (str == null)
    return str;
  return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(Math.Abs(length), str.Length));
}
```

Another solution would be to limit the length to be non-negative values, and just zero-out negative values.

```
public static string Left( this string str, int length ) {
  if (str == null)
    return str;
  return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(Math.Max(0,length), str.Length));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this:

```
var x= str== null 
        ? string.Empty 
        : str.Substring(0, Math.Min(5, str.Length));
```

Answer (score 3):

The only reason I can see the purpose in this is for DB storage. If so, why not let the DB handle it and then push the exception upstream to be dealt with at the presentation layer?

Comment: Sql Server silently truncates them, so I am thinking about building my own class just for this purpose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628140/sql-server-silently-truncates-varchars-in-stored-procedures

Comment: and what if i want to be able to handle that truncation without spending the time on a round-trip to the database (which can fail with an error that doesn't indicate which column was truncated)

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the if statement if you pad it out to the length you want to limit it to.

```
string name1 = "Christopher";
string name2 = "Jay";
int maxLength = 5;

name1 = name1.PadRight(maxLength).Substring(0, maxLength);
name2 = name2.PadRight(maxLength).Substring(0, maxLength);
```

name1 will have Chris

name2 will have Jay

No if statement needed to check the length before you use substring

Comment: Using .Trim() removes the spaces that have been added by .PadRight(maxlength) when the text.Length is smaller than maxLength, e.g.   "01234567890123456789".PadRight(30).Substring(0, 30).Trim()

Answer (score 1):

Use *Remove()*...

```
string foo = "1234567890";
int trimLength = 5;

if (foo.Length > trimLength) foo = foo.Remove(trimLength);

// foo is now "12345"
```

Answer (score -2):

foo = foo.Substring(0,5);

Comment: will cause an exception if foo is < 5 in length