# Error in Dynamic SQL SP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic, dynamic-sql

I Have created a procedure which has code like this:

```
   Create PROCEDURE Sample( @ID INT )
AS 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @SchemaName SYSNAME
    DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME
    DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME


     SELECT  @SQL = 'Create Table ' + @DatabaseName + '.'
            + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName
            + '_temp' + '('
    SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + 'ID int NOT NULL Primary Key, Name VarChar(10))'
```

I Always get error as :

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 77
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when using dynamic sql, I find it helpful to have it print the variable:

```
PRINT @SQL
```

That way you can take the output and look at it in the analyser

Comment: I tried adding print to the Procedure when It prints it is printing only until [Q18_RAW] [varchar](max) NULL,. Any Suggestions on why it is doing

Comment: The max for NVARCHAR is 4K characters.  Perhaps your SQL has a bunch of spaces in it?  Do a  PRINT LEN(@SQL) and see if it's 4K

Comment: This is not remotely true. `nvarchar(max)` allows a billion characters (2GB of data and 2 bytes per character)

Comment: @Martin - Sorry you're correct.  The maximum numerical value you can pass in the declaring statement is 4K.  I misread the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your string literal has an unfortunate length. Implicit string conversion from `varchar` to `nvarchar` truncates strings with a length between 4000 and 8000 characters to 4000 characters.

Use the `N` prefix before your string literal to avoid implicit string conversion.

Comment: Too long? I've never hit this issue myself. How long can a string literal be in TSQL?

Comment: @Martin - If you do direct assignment `@SQL = 'long string'` it works. But if you do `@SQL = @SQL + 'long string'` the literal can not have a datalength > 8000. I have never heard about this either I just discovered the behavior and have not found any documentation of the limit. It would be really nice if you could confirm that you see the same thing.

Comment: @Martin - I can't reproduce this any longer. Change the faulty code to use varchar instead to see the difference and the change back has somehow fixed it. I will look in to this more later. Strange indeed.

Comment: @Mikael - What was the datype of `@SQL` in your test? I just tried (SQL Server 2008) `declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''; set @sql = @sql + 'some very long text I pasted in'; select len(@sql)` and it returned `3776000` (Adding an `N` prefix before the literal didn't change the result either...)

Comment: @Martin - I use `nvarchar(max)`. I am now able to reproduce again using the string in version one of this question. The behavior I see now is the same as I described in my first comment. Adding `N` prefix makes it work.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. It cuts off after `[Q19_RAW] [varchar](max) NULL,`

Comment: It seems to me that if it is  >8000 characters then it is OK. But if it is between 4000 and 8000 characters it gets truncated.

Comment: @Martin It cuts every string that has a `datalength()` from 8000 to 16000. A string with 16001 characters works fine.

Comment: @Martin - :) Pretty much the same as I discovered.

Comment: @Mikael - I guess this must be a bug. Not something I've ever seen documented and certainly weird behaviour.

Comment: @Martin - Yes, most likely a bug. I tested in SQL Server 2005 and got the same thing from 4000 to 8000 chars. Above 8000 I got `The data types nvarchar(max) and text are incompatible in the add operator.` Since the string is not nvarchar because of the lacking `N` I guess that it is treated as a varchar with a specific length until it passes 8000 chars. The string then gets truncated by the implicit string conversion from varchar to nvarchar.

Comment: It's not restricted to string literals. If I try `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''; declare @t table(c varchar(8000)) insert into @t values (replicate('A',8000)) select LEN(@sql + c) from @t`  I see the same results. In the compute scalar in the plan `varchar(8000)` gets implicitly converted to `nvarchar(4000)` maybe this is documented somewhere...

Comment: @Martin - I think I should update my answer :). BTW you can simplify the fail concatenation to this `LEN(N''+c)`

Comment: @Mikael - Agreed but that wouldn't be as surprising to me. I think I was expecting the cast to be `nvarchar(max)` as the concatenation was to an `nvarchar(max)` variable. Evidently that's not the way it works!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `PRINT`. Chances are that the `PRINT` output itself will be truncated with long text.  Use

```
SELECT @SQL as [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH
```

to inspect the values of such variables in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your initial declaration of @SQL to `DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)` and it worked (instead of NVARCHAR).