# Query returns correct results, stored proc does not. Need a second set of eyes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My Query:

```
select
  *
from
  meet_cert_credit
where
  conf_number = '1132'
  and type_of_professional = 'Certified Hazardous Materials Managers'
```

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_check_credit_info] 

@cn varchar = NULL,
@top varchar = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select 
    * 
from 
    meet_cert_credit 
where 
    Conf_number = @cn 
    and type_of_professional = @top
END
```

Calling my stored proc:

`exec sp_check_credit_info '1132', 'Certified Hazardous Materials Managers'`

When running the query, it returns results. When running the stored procedure, I get nothing.

Am I insane?

Comment: Probably unrelated, in SQL Server stored procedure names starting with  `sp_` are reserved for system stored procedures. See "Naming Stored Procedures" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190669(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to give a length to your `varchar` stored procedure parameters.

e.g. use `@cn varchar(30)` not `@cn varchar`

Currently everything you are passing in is getting truncated to 1 character so you are effectively doing the following search.

```
select 
    * 
from 
    meet_cert_credit 
where 
    Conf_number = '1' 
    and type_of_professional = 'C'
```

Hence no results.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Comment: +1, I thought the default of an unspecified length `varchar` strings was 30, but here it is being truncated to 1 char, try it out: `declare @x varchar; set @x='123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+';select @x` **moral of the story, always specify the length of string!!!**

Comment: @KM - Yes, `CAST(@X AS VARCHAR)` defaults to 30 but in this context it is 1 for some reason.

Comment: I always define the length on params to avoid errors (if the string > the field size). The truncation is a cool tidbit.

Comment: "When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx I'm surprised the truncation does not generate an error.

Comment: @Shannon - Yep [this happens silently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4628140/73226) and [can be a security concern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163523.aspx)