# Ridiculous thing in SQL Select query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[User_SelectByLoginID]
@LoginID nvarChar(4)
as
SELECT dbo.[User].*
FROM  dbo.[User]
WHERE LoginID=@LoginID
```

And data in the User table:

```
LoginID ='1111'  |  Name ='abc'  |  Email = 'abc@yahoo.com'
```

when I executed this query and typed in '1111111', it returned the record:

```
1111    abc    abc@yahoo.com
```

it is ridiculous when I entered the wrong LoginID and still got the data.

P/S: I set LoginID `nvarchar(4)`

Can someone explain for me? And how to make it right?

Comment: Are you just wanting to rant/vent about the fact that SQL Server silently truncates overlong parameters? Or do you have an actual question?

Comment: You might want to look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4628331/15498) for links to connect items asking Microsoft to make (opt-in) stricter settings available.

Comment: The ID is wrong but so  is the stored procedure so together they are right!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server silently truncates varchar's in stored procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628140/sql-server-silently-truncates-varchars-in-stored-procedures)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is my first time coming cross this thing, so I just want to ask to make it clear. Don't think negatively like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set @LoginID to nvarchar(4) it will truncate to that size so really you are passing in 1111 and not 11111111.

Comment: could you tell me How I can fix it? OR which type I should use for LoginID?

Comment: you can set `@LoginID` more than 4 then it will not show the result

Comment: Simply do not set the nvarchar to 4 (or any value) or set it to a value higher than the length of your input.

Comment: @andrew-buchan Are you saying to use `nvarchar` with no parentheses at all? That is a huge mistake, because in various contexts it either means `nvarchar(30)` or `nvarchar(1)`. **Always**, always, *always* specify a data length. In SQL Server there is no concept of a lengthless char/varchar parameter.

Comment: @ErikE - `varchar(max)` must surely come close to a lengthless parameter?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How close is 2147483647 to infinity? In my book `1/infinity = 2147483647/infinity`. `varchar(max)` has a length.

Comment: @ErikE - ah, but [what is the limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611394/maximum-size-of-a-varcharmax-variable)? I believe that a parameter would follow the same path as a variable, rather than a non-FILESTREAM column.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Interesting, but it doesn't really change my point. `varchar(max)` is not a good data type to use unless you expect your data to exceed 8000 characters.

Comment: @ErikE - well, I guess I've missed what you're aiming for. Your first comment stated that there's no "lengthless" option available (whatever that may mean). I've then pointed you at options that have no (apparent) length limit. Whilst I agree with your general gist (specify the length if you can), I'm not sure what point you're trying to make more broadly. Can you point to a language that has a lengthless string that is worth studying?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sure, I'll be more clear. `varchar(max)` is not lengthless. It has a length of `max`, which is whatever the maximum limit is in that version of SQL Server. Furthermore, if the variable is to be used to reference a column's value in a table, then it IS limited to some fixed amount, as shown in the same post that you linked me to above.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server silently truncates your value passed to stored procedure, so even though you pass value '1111111', it is cut off to the declared length (4) so in your stored procedure there is a value '1111'.

So you should declare your parameter @LoginID to the same size which has your column LoginID in User table